# Macro issue while reading the data from txt file and storing it in excel file

Tags: vba, excel

I need to read multiple txt file one by one and read the data from it and store it in excel sheet. Getting issue with the last value from the first txt file and also when my macro is reading the second file, it is clubbing the content of the first txt file and also truncating the content from the second file. PLease could you advise.

Regard

'Sub copy_data()

Dim myFile As String, text As String, textline As String, posvalueFieldTagName As Integer, posnextFieldTagName As Integer, fieldTagValue As String

Dim dataFile, nextFieldTagName, startFieldTagName As String
Dim y As Workbook

Dim z, i, j, lenTagValue, sample1, sample2 As Integer
Dim FilePath, FileOnly, PathOnly As String

Dim cIn, cOut, cIO, a, b, c, d, rCount As Integer

Dim dataFileIn, dataFileOut, fieldVal  As String

Set y = ThisWorkbook

```
For i = 1 To y.Sheets.Count

'Either we can put all names in an array , here we are printing all the names in Sheet 2

y.Sheets("sheetName").Range("A" & i) = y.Sheets(i).Name

Next i
```

y.Save

For z = 1 To y.Sheets("sheetName").UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1

```
    cIn = 0
    cOut = 0
    cIO = 0
    dataFile = y.Worksheets("sheetName").Cells(1, z).Value
    dataFileIn = dataFile & "I"
    dataFileOut = dataFile & "O"
    rCount = y.Sheets(dataFile).UsedRange.Rows.Count

    For a = 2 To rCount

    fieldVal = y.Worksheets(dataFile).Cells(a, 1).Value
    fieldVal = Trim(fieldVal)

            If fieldVal = dataFile & "I" Then
            cIn = cIn + 1
            End If

            If fieldVal = dataFile & "O" Then
            cOut = cOut + 1
            End If

            If fieldVal = dataFile Then
            cIO = cIO + 1
            End If

   Next a

   fieldVal = Trim(y.Worksheets(dataFile).Cells(z + 1, 1).Value)

If fieldVal = dataFile Then

                FilePath = ThisWorkbook.FullName
                FileOnly = ThisWorkbook.Name
                PathOnly = Left(FilePath, Len(FilePath) - Len(FileOnly))

                myFile = PathOnly & dataFile & ".txt"

                Open myFile For Input As #1

                                     Do Until EOF(1)
                                         Line Input #1, textline
                                         text = text & textline

                                     Loop
                                     MsgBox (text)
                                     Close #1

            For b = 2 To cIO - 1
                    startFieldTagName = y.Worksheets(dataFile).Range("F" & b).Value
                    If InStr(text, startFieldTagName) = 0 Then
                    Exit For
                    Else

                    nextFieldTagName = y.Worksheets(dataFile).Range("F" & b + 1).Value

                    posvalueFieldTagName = InStr(text, startFieldTagName) + 1 + Len(startFieldTagName)

                    posnextFieldTagName = InStr(text, nextFieldTagName)

                        If posnextFieldTagName = 0 Then
                        posnextFieldTagName = Len(text)
                        Else
                        posnextFieldTagName = InStr(text, nextFieldTagName)
                        End If

                    lenTagValue = posnextFieldTagName - posvalueFieldTagName

                    fieldTagValue = Mid(text, posvalueFieldTagName, lenTagValue)
                    y.Worksheets(dataFile).Range("I" & b).Value = CStr(fieldTagValue)
                    End If

                Next b
               y.Save
Else
   FilePath = ThisWorkbook.FullName
   FileOnly = ThisWorkbook.Name
   PathOnly = Left(FilePath, Len(FilePath) - Len(FileOnly))

   myFile = PathOnly & dataFile & "I" & ".txt"

   Open myFile For Input As #1

                        Do Until EOF(1)
                            Line Input #1, textline
                            text = text & textline

                        Loop
                        MsgBox (text)
                        Close #1
   For c = 2 To cIn - 1
                             startFieldTagName = y.Worksheets(dataFile).Range("F" & c).Value
                             If InStr(text, startFieldTagName) = 0 Then
                             Exit For
                             Else

                             nextFieldTagName = y.Worksheets(dataFile).Range("F" & c + 1).Value
                             posvalueFieldTagName = InStr(text, startFieldTagName) + 1 + Len(startFieldTagName)
                              posnextFieldTagName = InStr(text, nextFieldTagName)

                                If posnextFieldTagName = 0 Then
                                posnextFieldTagName = Len(text)
                                Else
                                posnextFieldTagName = InStr(text, nextFieldTagName)
                                End If
                              lenTagValue = posnextFieldTagName - posvalueFieldTagName
                             fieldTagValue = Mid(text, posvalueFieldTagName, lenTagValue)
                              y.Worksheets(dataFile).Range("I" & c).Value = CStr(fieldTagValue)


                            fieldTagValue = y.Worksheets(dataFile).Range("I" & c).Value
                            If fieldTagValue <> "" Then

                            y.Worksheets(dataFile).Range("J" & c).Value = "Y"

                            Else

                            y.Worksheets(dataFile).Range("J" & c).Value = "N"
                            y.Worksheets(dataFile).Range("G" & c).Value = "Blank Space"
                            y.Worksheets(dataFile).Range("I" & c).Value = "Blank Space"

                            End If


                            End If
             Next c
                            ' MsgBox (y.Worksheets(dataFile).Cells(8, i).Value)
                            y.Save

   myFile = PathOnly & dataFile & "O" & ".txt"

   Open myFile For Input As #2

                        Do Until EOF(2)
                            Line Input #2, textline
                            text = text & textline

                        Loop
                        MsgBox (text)
                        Close #2
    For d = cIn + 2 To cOut - 1
                             startFieldTagName = y.Worksheets(dataFile).Range("F" & d).Value
                             If InStr(text, startFieldTagName) = 0 Then
                             Exit For
                             Else

                             nextFieldTagName = y.Worksheets(dataFile).Range("F" & d + 1).Value
                             posvalueFieldTagName = InStr(text, startFieldTagName) + 1 + Len(startFieldTagName)
                             posnextFieldTagName = InStr(text, nextFieldTagName)

                             If posnextFieldTagName = 0 Then
                             posnextFieldTagName = Len(text)
                             Else
                             posnextFieldTagName = InStr(text, nextFieldTagName)
                             End If
                              lenTagValue = posnextFieldTagName - posvalueFieldTagName
                             fieldTagValue = Mid(text, posvalueFieldTagName, lenTagValue)
                             MsgBox (fieldTagValue)

                             y.Worksheets(dataFile).Range("I" & d).Value = CStr(fieldTagValue)
                            End If
            Next d
            y.Save
```

End If

Next z

y.Save

y.Close

End Sub
'

Comment: Where is the code you tried to use?

Comment: A sample code which you have tried so far would be helpful for us to provide a right answer for you.

Comment: I have added my code also in the detail. Please could you look into it and help me

Comment: No answer to your problem, but your code does contain errors in the declarations. A Statement like this: Dim cIn, cOut, cIO, a, b, c, d, rCount As Integer ONLY declares the LAST variable as Integer, all others are Variants. In VBA you must add the As clause for each variable individually: Dim cIn  As Integer, cOut As Integer, cIO As Integer, a As Integer, b As Integer, c As Integer, d As Integer, rCount As Integer